# Horizontal Average SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID   Value1   Value2   Value3
1    10       0        5
2    12       10       20
3    0        5        9
4    20       12       8
5    2        15       0
```

I want to have the following result:

```
ID   avgValue
1    7.5
2    14
3    7
4    13.33
5    8.5
```

The formula is normal average but the average calculation is always skip the zero value.
Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is to choose denominator count based on 0 value of three columns..

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d36c31/4

```
    select 
    id,
    cast((value1+value2+value3) as float)/ 
    (
    case when value1>0 then 1 else 0 end
    +
    case when value2>0 then 1 else 0 end
    +
    case when value3>0 then 1 else 0 end
    )
    as avgValue

    from test
```

Please let me know whether it works for you..